# How to fix Window.getComputedStyle is not an object error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, getcomputedstyle

I am trying to use draggabilly available at 
 https://github.com/desandro/draggabilly

it works fine in html. Now when i have tried to add it in wordpress. I am getting following error in firebug console.

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle is not an object.
return s.getComputedStyle(t, null)
```

here is a link for js file
http://draggabilly.desandro.com/draggabilly.pkgd.min.js

Comment: Did you look at what `t` is in either the debugger or `console.log(t)`?  That seems kind of the obvious first step and then look back at how you populate `t` for ideas on why it isn't set properly.

Comment: thanks for reply. I got it working. I just copied complete html code for demo in wordpress.

Comment: In d3.js, you will get this error if you try to make a selection on a non-existent dom object.

Comment: @Incodeveritas Thanks for commenting - though I'm not using D3, you led me to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling init twice. Go through your code and remove one instance.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error testing my project with IE8: finally it was so obvious, this method doen't work with IE 8!

```
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method at: http://...
```

I received this error with FF that does support this method but I forgot to change `window` to my frame window object!

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(window.document.querySelector('.tip > .tip.top'), ':after').getPropertyValue('left'));
TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle is not an object.
at: http://...
```

Note that the above error pops up even if your `window` object is ok but the `querySelector` returns nothing! (I suspect it's your case).