# skrollr.min.js is not initializing

Tags: javascript, skrollr

```
var s = skrollr.init({    
    mobileDeceleration: 1,    
    edgeStrategy: 'set',    
    forceHeight: true,    
    smoothScrolling: true,    
    smoothScrollingDuration: 300,   
    easing: {    
        WTF: Math.random,
        inverted: function(p) {
            return 1-p;
        }
    }
});
```

When i try to init skrollr it just gives me this error:
TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle is not an object.
What could it be?

Comment: Are you by any chance using IE8? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899272/how-to-fix-window-getcomputedstyle-is-not-an-object-error

Comment: LoL nope, i'm using mozilla firefox.

Comment: When are you calling `init`? Is the DOM ready at this point (e.g. at the end of the page and not inside the head)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same issue and putting the init inside $(document).ready resolved it for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var s = skrollr.init();
});
```